# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_hostElement')

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to go through a little project I have and add unit tests into it, I'm having issues getting a specific component to be created.

I'm using Angular 15.1.3. I have no idea what I could be missing. I currently get the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_hostElement')` when fixture.detectChanges(); is called.

This is what I believe are the relevant section of code

loot-generator.component.spec.ts

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LootGeneratorComponent } from './loot-generator.component';
import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatCard, MatCardActions, MatCardContent, MatCardHeader, MatCardTitle } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSlideToggle } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSlider, MatSliderVisualThumb } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';

describe('LootGeneratorComponent', () => {
  let component: LootGeneratorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LootGeneratorComponent>;
  const snackBarSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MatSnackBar', ['open']);
  const clipboardSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Clipboard', ['beginCopy']);

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, MatRippleModule ],
      declarations: [
        LootGeneratorComponent,
        MatCard,
        MatCardHeader,
        MatCardTitle,
        MatCardContent,
        MatSlideToggle,
        MatSlider,
        MatCardActions,
        MatSliderVisualThumb
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: MatSnackBar, useValue: snackBarSpy},
        {provide: Clipboard, useValue: clipboardSpy}
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LootGeneratorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();  // Error is shown here 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_hostElement')
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

loot-generator.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CoinType } from './enums/coin.enum';
import { TreasureType } from './enums/treasure.enum';
import { Loot } from './models/loot.model';
import { TreasureGenerator } from './services/treasure-generator.service';
import { Clipboard } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Coin } from './models/coin.model';
import { ICoin } from './interfaces/coin.interface';
import { Treasure } from './models/treasure.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loot-generator',
  templateUrl: './loot-generator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loot-generator.component.css']
})
export class LootGeneratorComponent {
  private generator: TreasureGenerator = new TreasureGenerator();

  public challengeRating: number = 1;
  public groupLoot: boolean = false;
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['coin', 'amount']
  public displayTreasureColumns: string[] = ['treasure', 'name', 'value']
  public loot: Loot = new Loot();

  constructor(
    private clipboard: Clipboard,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

// ... bunch 'o methods which are omitted for brevity. I doubt they are the issue as they aren't even called yet
```

loot-generator.html

```html
<mat-card class="card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Loot Generation Options</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <section class="options">
      <div>
        <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="groupLoot" name="groupLoot">Hoard Loot</mat-slide-toggle>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-slider class="slider" min="1" max="20" step="1" discrete>
          <input matSliderThumb [(ngModel)]="challengeRating">
        </mat-slider>
        <label id="slider-name-label" class="slider-name-label">CR</label>
        <label id="slider-value-label" class="slider-value-label">
        {{challengeRating}}
        </label>
      </div>
    </section>
    <mat-card-actions class="options-buttons">
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        color="primary"
        (click)="generateLoot()">Generate</button>
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        color="accent"
        (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>

<mat-card class="card" *ngIf="loot.coins.length > 0 || loot.treasures.length > 0">
  <mat-card-header>
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          matTooltip="Copy to clipboard"
          aria-label="Copy to clipboard"
          (click)="onCopyToClipboardClick()">
          <mat-icon>content_copy</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button
          mat-icon-button
          matTooltip="Sell Loot"
          aria-label="Sell Loot"
          (click)="onSellClick()">
          <mat-icon>sell</mat-icon>
        </button>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card class="card" *ngIf="loot.coins.length > 0">
    <table
      #coinTable
      *ngIf="loot.coins.length > 0"
      mat-table
      id="0"
      [dataSource]="loot.coins">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="coin">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Coin </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getCoinName(element.type)}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Amount </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-flat-button>Re-Roll</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </mat-card>

  <mat-card class="card" *ngIf="loot.treasures.length > 0">
    <table
      #treasureTable
      *ngIf="loot.treasures.length > 0"
      mat-table
      id="1"
      [dataSource]="loot.treasures">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="treasure">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Treasure </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getTreasureTypeName(element.type)}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value (gp)</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value === 0 ? '-' : element.value}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-flat-button>Re-Roll</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayTreasureColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayTreasureColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error when you're generating the component that you're testing. The error is most likely something that the included material components (or one / some of them ) require.

I usually stub library components, but I managed to find a resource which mentions the following:

> ComponentHarness is the abstract base class for all component harnesses. Every harness extends this class. All ComponentHarness subclasses have a static property, hostSelector, that matches the harness class to instances of the component in the DOM. Beyond that, the API of any given harness is specific to its corresponding component; refer to the component's documentation to learn how to use a specific harness

It may be a good read for your problem (it has an overview and API part like the usual material component documentation): https://material.angular.io/cdk/test-harnesses/overview#component-test-harnesses

Comment: It turns out I had my imports and declarations a bit mixed up, I ended up changing the imports section to `imports: [ FormsModule, MatRippleModule, MatCardModule, ....`

Comment: Ah, that happens, too! I guess you should write it as an answer and accept it to your question, since noone answered and you figured it out.